# How can I adjust door hinges to fix a sagging door?

Tags: doors, hinges

The door to the kitchen is sagging quite badly, damaging the floor. The door is heavy, so before inviting a friend and taking it off the hinges, I wanted to ask for advice. Maybe someone has had a similar issue before.

The door has a decent gap on one side and no gap at all on the other. It is attached by drilled-in hinges with two screws at the bottom and one at the top. What do you think could be the best way to adjust these things? And is it even possible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: We need a little more info (and probably better photos).  Have you tried *tightening the screws?*

Comment: This isn't a hinge problem. It's a _jamb_ problem. I can't tell from your closeups how that all connects, though.

Comment: The hinge looks slightly bent too, which could be a lube/wear issue inside it.